# Integration of Python code into a C# application when python code contains numpy

Tags: c#, python, numpy, ironpython, pythonnet

I am currently developing an app which is primarily based in `.NET` but need to integrate some math based code which is in `Python3` and contains many references to the `numpy`, `scipy` and `pandas` packages.

I have read that `IronPython` will not support these packages and that `pythonnet` cannot be embedded into a `C#` application to use from .net.....

The python functions need to receive arguements of type dictionary, list and user defined class from the c# application and then return dictionaries that can be interpreted by the c# code.

Is there a way to integrate the two code bases in their current format or to maintain the functionality does the python code need to be re-scripted into another language?

Comment: Why don't you create some `Restful` services with Python and call them from `C#` application?

Comment: If you need a lighter weight solution than a rest api, you could use sockets to send data between the two applications.

Comment: @anna where did you see that pythonnet cannot be used for embedding python in .net? here is tutorial: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @denfromufa I saw that information here:  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Python-for-NET-and-IronPython

Comment: @the_storyteller are sockest simpler than rest api?

Comment: @cikatomo, A rest API is a high level abstraction for moving structured data. Sockets are the things which actually move the data. A rest API can be used in concert with a text transport protocol and sockets to provide a nice way to send and receive data. However, it's also possible to send the raw data directly through the sockets, without the high level interface.